# Suddenly my visual studio and codeblock started showing errors

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw

Suddenly my vs code and code block started showing errors
In VS Code, it highlights the header file and says "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit"

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyEPA.png)

and code block says "A debugging check in this application has failed"

[image]

I tried reinstalling both MinGW and ide, but still, the problem persists
I also checked my environmental variable, it is also fine
Please help me with it

Comment: The errors look unrelated. The VSC one can be fixed just by telling it where to look for the headers (see answer below).

Comment: Check the path in your `c_cpp_properties.json` for the intellisense problem in VSCode. The second problem should be a totally different question. I also agree it appears to be completly unrelated to the first.

Comment: I recommend that you follow this microsoft tutorial on using VSCode with mingw. It will help you understand how VSCode uses the .json files for compilation, debugging and Intellisense. Here is the tutorial: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual-studio, go ahead and enable the errorSquiggles setting, then from there you should be able to click on the red squiggly line underneath to view suggestions of how to update your configurations. This alone in theory should work, however if not then you may need to manually find the .json files for IntelliSense and compilation.

source for error: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_intellisense

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, but error is still there, I tried putting the address of library file in IncludePath of c_cpp_properties.json as it was asking but still problem was unsolved. But my program is still running in vs code.